# Identifying if the user presses <enter>

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, trim

I have been working on this for several days and I'm super frustrated. This is my first course in Java so please bear with me on lack of knowledge still. I'm supposed to write a program that contains an array of 10 grades entered by the user and I calculate the average. In particular I'm having problems with what is down below.

You should not read doubles numbers from the user, you should read a string. Here is the process:

Read a string from the user
trim the string and get the length
if the length <1 then the user hit  and you get out
if the length is >0 then you convert the string into a double using

```
d =Double.parseDouble(S);
```

So far I just have this. I have been adding and deleting a lot of coding to this for the past week. And I still cant seem to get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Arrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       double d = 0;
       final int SIZE = 10;
       Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
       String[ ] grades = new String[SIZE];

       System.out.println("Please enter up to 10 grades.");

       for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++){
           System.out.print("Grade " + (i + 1) + ": "); 
           grades[i] = reader.nextLine( );
       }

       System.out.println("\nNumber of valid grades entered: " + grades.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what your exact question is? Are you getting an error? If yes, on which line?

Comment: Your code works for me - after I enter 10 values, it prints "Number of valid grades entered: 10"

Comment: You don't so much detect pressing enter as expect certain kinds of tokens using your scanner and nextLine, nextInt, nextDouble, etc - which will be delimited by pressing enter naturally.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; ){
   System.out.print("Grade " + (i + 1) + ": "); 
   String str = reader.nextLine();
   if(str.trim().length() > 0){
       try{
           grades[i] = Double.parseDouble(str);
           i++;
       }catch(NumberFormatException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
System.out.println("\nNumber of valid grades entered: " + i);
```

IMHO i think grades should be an array of `double` ie

```
 double[] grades=new double[SIZE];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in following way

```
 int correctGrades=0;
 double[] grades=new double[SIZE];  //Create array of double instead of String
 for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    System.out.print("Grade " + (i + 1) + ": "); 
    String str=reader.nextLine();
    if(str.length() > 0){ // If length is greater than 0 then its correct grade
      grades[i]=Double.parseDouble(str);
      correctGrades++;
    }
}
 System.out.println("\nNumber of valid grades entered: " + correctGrades);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding this should be your for loop

```
for (int i = 0; true; i++) {
      System.out.print("Grade " + (i + 1) + ": ");
      grades[i] = reader.nextLine();
      if (grades[i].equals("")) {
        break;
      }
       //check for number format exception if user enters invalid input 
      try {
        d = Double.parseDouble(grades[i]);
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
       exception.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  System.out.println("The value of double entered is : " + d);
    }
```

Here you run the loop for infinite number of times but with every loop you check the user input.
Now if the user enters an empty string you exit the loop using the break statement